# Postgresql error: "failed to find conversion function from unknown to text"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following postgresql query:

```
   with A as 
   (
          select '201405MASE04' as TestID, Count(*) TotQ, Count(distinct Case When SE1 = '' then NULL else SE1 end) TotSE, 
                 case when Count(*)=0 then 7 else Count(distinct RC) end TotRC
          from eivTestItems TI, eivTests T 
          where TI.Test_ID = T.Test_ID 
                 and T.Test_Type_ID = 1
                 and T.Test_ID=  '201405MASE04'
                 and TI.Omit <> 1
   ), 
   B as 
   (
          select '201405MASE04' as TestID, Count(*) TotQ
          from eivTestItems TI, eivTests T 
          where TI.Test_ID = T.Test_ID 
                 and T.Test_Type_ID = 1
                 and T.Test_ID=  '201405MASE04'
                 and TI.Omit = 1
   ),
   C as
   (
          select '201405MASE04' as TestID, Count(*) TotQ
          from eivTestItems TI, eivTests T 
          where TI.Test_ID = T.Test_ID 
                 and T.Test_Type_ID = 1
                 and T.Test_ID=  '201405MASE04'
                 and TI.Question_Type_ID='2'
   )

   Select A.TestID, A.TotQ + coalesce(B.TotQ,0) - coalesce(C.TotQ,0) as TotQ, A.TotSE, A.TotRC
   From A
   left outer Join B on A.TestID = B.TestID
   left outer Join C on A.TestID = C.TestID
```

When i am trying to run this query, it is throwing me the following error:

```
ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to text

********** Error **********

ERROR: failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
SQL state: XX000
```

How do i find out where am i getting the conversion error here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like postgres doesn't like your constant '201405MASE04'.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9450f/9)** that generates the same error you get.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9450f/8)** showing the cast the datatype fixes the issue.

Try this. I define it as text

```
with A as 
   (
          select cast('201405MASE04' as text) as TestID, Count(*) TotQ, Count(distinct Case When SE1 = '' then NULL else SE1 end) TotSE, 
                 case when Count(*)=0 then 7 else Count(distinct RC) end TotRC
          from eivTestItems TI, eivTests T 
          where TI.Test_ID = T.Test_ID 
                 and T.Test_Type_ID = 1
                 and T.Test_ID=  '201405MASE04'
                 and TI.Omit <> 1
   ), 
   B as 
   (
          select cast('201405MASE04' as text) as TestID, Count(*) TotQ
          from eivTestItems TI, eivTests T 
          where TI.Test_ID = T.Test_ID 
                 and T.Test_Type_ID = 1
                 and T.Test_ID=  '201405MASE04'
                 and TI.Omit = 1
   ),
   C as
   (
          select cast('201405MASE04' as text) as TestID, Count(*) TotQ
          from eivTestItems TI, eivTests T 
          where TI.Test_ID = T.Test_ID 
                 and T.Test_Type_ID = 1
                 and T.Test_ID=  '201405MASE04'
                 and TI.Question_Type_ID='2'
   )

   Select A.TestID, A.TotQ + coalesce(B.TotQ,0) - coalesce(C.TotQ,0) as TotQ, A.TotSE, A.TotRC
   From A
   left outer Join B on A.TestID = B.TestID
   left outer Join C on A.TestID = C.TestID
```